# Convert boot hdd to RAID 1 array

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid

I've added another hdd to my 'server' since I wanted to clone it using RAID. 
I've read several articles about converting an existing filesystem to a RAID 1 system. They all use software, and I want to use hardware.

Are the disks formatted when I add the raid array? (I'll make a full backup first of course, any suggestions about how to do that?)

The motherboard: 
ASRock N68PV-GS

Chipset:
NVIDIA GeForce 7050/nForce 630A MCP Chipset

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: Image the hard drive, create raid 1 array, apply image to array.

Comment: With fdisk or dd??

Comment: Which hardware do you wish to use? If you use a dedicated RAID card then that card will likely change the disk contents by writing some of its own information to disk. Almost all HW RAID cards do this.

Comment: As to the full backup first: Which OS? If it is BSD or Linux you might get away by booting a live CD, creating partitions and filesystems, restoring the backup and adjusting /etc/fstab. If it is windows you might run into a driver problem.

Comment: @Hennes I'm planning to configure raid from my bios. It is Ubuntu

Comment: Does the raid config in your BIOS control an on-board hardware RAID card (usually on expensive workstation or server motherboards) or is it merely an interface to help software RAID (aka fakeraid).

Comment: @Hennes haven't figured that out yet. But in my manual it shows connector: 4 x SATA , support raid (raid 0,1,0+1,5 jbod) and I found a manual about using the raid functionality on my mobo

Comment: If it does not explicitly mention HW RAID then it is almost always software RAID with firmware support. In which case the OS (or more specific, the drivers for this SW RAID) become very relevant. If Linux or BSD then there are already plenty answers about it (search for mdadm on SU and SF).

Comment: @Hennes Thanks, I hope that the backup is almost finished, if it is. I'll look into the config, and try things out.

Comment: @Hennes Due to the NVIDIA chipset, I was able to successfully create a RAID 1 array ^^. Proceeding to put back the disk image now. Thanks for the help

Comment: **Crosses fingers**. If that worked then please post what you did as an answer. INcluding RAID options and the remark that windows $version recognised the new array (aka it had the drivers already build in) or how you added those drivers.

Comment: @Hennes I'll post the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a motherboard that supports hardware RAID (check your motherboard's manual for this) you can proceed with this 'guide'.

Check if your RAID array needs drivers to function (this might be the case if you use a dedicated controller (apart from the default SATA controller on your motherboard), if yes install them on the 'target' computer that we will be converting to a RAID array **FIRST** before you proceed. If you don't to this step, your computer might not boot up after the restoration of the disk image.

We are going to make a mirrored RAID (a.k.a. RAID-1) array.

***WARNING: Backup ALL your important data to a SEPARATE (usb) hard drive.***

- Now we are going to create a disk image of the hdd that you want to
  convert to a RAID array, I've done this by taking out the hdd that
  needed to be converted to a RAID array, connected it to a SATA reader
  and downloaded [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) to create a disk image. (see the
  settings below)

  [ If you don't have a SATA reader, install the software on your
  Windows machine, launch it, and create a Rescue disk (burn it on a cd
  or put it on an usb). Then boot from your medium and select backup. ]

Make sure you use these settings:

Compression: Medium (Recommended) **AND SELECT "Make an exact copy of the partition(s)."**
File size: Automatic
Password: I recommend none
Auto Verify Image: Yes
Comments: -
Shutdown: The choice is up to you

- Using the "Make an exact copy of the partition(s)." will copy every
  single sector of the disk. With my experience the final image size
  isn't the same as the full disk size, but it's recommended to get a
  empty hdd that sizes the hdd you want to create an image of as a
  minimum. (Preferably bigger)
- Click finish.. and wait for the backup to finish.

***WARNING: Make sure you've backed up all your data, proceeding with the steps below will format both the hdds that you are going to use for the RAID 1 array.***

- When your backup is complete, and verified, go into the bios settings
  of your motherboard.
- Make sure to check your motherboards manual to select the right
  options.  Create a new RAID array with the 'type' Mirrored to create
  a RAID 1 array.

**Make sure to clear your MBR if it is possible!**

- Wait for the array to create.
- Then boot into the rescue disk (see what to do if you don't have a
  SATA reader section to create a boot disk)

Then restore the image on the drive that has the same name as the name in the RAID configurator. (This is important!)

Sometimes Macrium Reflect will list that your array contains several partitions, just rescan for drives (or reboot the rescue disk)

- Then click the array that you want to put your data back on and click
  restore.
- Wait for the process to complete, then reboot your computer and boot
  from the RAID array (this should be done automatically)
- When you see a single drive that lists the size of your raid array
  you have successfully created a raid array.

I was using a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows config, and restored the image to the array. I didn't need to install any drivers at all and booted right back into Ubuntu.